# Что быстрее сравнивать, указатели или значения в с++?

Tags: c++, указатели

- Имеется std::vector, в каждом из них ещё vector'ы, в каждом из них
  ещё vector'ы.
- Случай 0: В самом последнем вложенном vector лежат числа размером в 1
  байт, варианты значений: 0,1,2.
  `vector<unsigned char> v;` Само сравнение: `if (char0 == char1)`
- Случай 1: В самом последнем вложенном vector лежат указатели на числа
  размером в 1 байт. Варианты значений: 0,1,2., но в vector хранятся только указатели на них. Само сравнение: `if (ptr_char0 == ptr_char1)`

  int i0=0;
  int i1=1;
  int i2=2;
  `vector<unsigned char*> v;`
- Случай 2: аналогично случаю 1, но будут браться для сравнения значения по указателям. Само сравнение: `if (*ptr_char0 == *ptr_char1)`
- Длины каждого "уровня" vector разные и меняются со временем. Нужно
  пройти все элементы и провести сравнение (только на равенство). Что-то удалить, что-то
  изменить, где-то добавить элементы или vector, но шаблон действия (if-else) одинаковые для обоих случаев.

Быстрее будет сравнивать переменные или указатели, или брать для сравнения значения по указателям, или ещё какой-то вариант?

Следующий пример показал, что самый быстрый случай #2, который наоборот должен быть самым медленным способом.

```
    int n0=10;
    int n1=20;
    int *p0 = &n0;
    int *p1 = &n1;
    int *q0 = &n0;
    int *q1 = &n1;
    int time0 = clock();
    for (int i=0;i!=25500000;++i)
    if (n0==n1){}
    int time1 = clock();
    for (int i=0;i!=25500000;++i)
    if (p0==p1){}
    int time2 = clock();
    for (int i=0;i!=25500000;++i)
    if (*q0==*q1){}
    int time3 = clock();

    printf("%i  %i  %i  %i",time0,time1,time2,time3);
```

Выхлоп: `311 312 313 313`

Очевидно, нагрузка слишком мала в этом примере, оценить трудно.

Comment: Ну напишите программу и поэкспериментируйте. Любые теоретические рассуждения без эксперимента ничего не стоят. А проще всего - не бегать по векторам, а просто сравнить на равенство два внешних - они уж сами разберутся, как поэлементно сравнивать...

Comment: @Глеб Сравнивать указатели не имеет смысла. Сравнивать сами значения очевидно по крайней мере не медленнее, чем использовать для сравнения указатели на значения и их разыменовывать для сравнения.

Comment: @Глеб Это при условии, что указатели указывают на один и тот же элемент и лежат в диапазоне массива.

Comment: Вообще судя по вопросу - сравнивать только значения.

Comment: @Глеб: Ну так а что если у вас `int a = 123, b = 123; int *p = &a, *q = &b;`. Что вы хотите получить в таком случае при сравнении `p` и `q` и как вы собираетесь обойтись "сравнением указателей"?

Comment: @AnT упростил и дополнил пример.

Answer (score 1):

Если в контексте вашей задачи постулируется эквивалентность:

```
равные указатели <=> равные указуемые значения
```

то разумеется в общем случае выгоднее будет просто сравнивать указатели, вместо того, чтобы разадресовывать указатели, вычитывать из памяти конкретные значения и потом сравнивать значения.

При этом следует помнить, что *относительные* сравнения произвольных указателей поддерживаются только через `std::less` и прочие стандартные предикаты относительного сравнения, но не через встроенные операторы `<`, `>` и т.п. Последние разрешают сравнение только указателей, указывающих на подобъекты одного объекта с рядом дополнительных ограничений.

Для операторов сравнения указателей на равенство `==` и `!=` таких ограничений нет.